# Requests/urllib3 error: unorderable types: Retry() < int()

Tags: session, python-3.x, subclass, python-requests, urllib3

I understand the error, yet do no understand it in the context of my code. This is in Python 3.4. The relevant bits of code (simplified somewhat for clarity):

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

class SessionAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):

        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                        maxsize=maxsize,
                                        block=block,
                                        ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                                        cert_reqs = 'CERT_REQUIRED',
                                        ca_certs = certifi.where(),
                                        )

try:

    app_session = requests.Session()

    app_session.mount('https://', SessionAdapter())

    app_response = app_session.post(
        url = 'https://<FQD URL>'
        , auth = (user, password)
        , verify = True
        )

    # Code errors on the previous line and never executes the logger line

    logger.debug('Status code: {}'.format(app_response.status_code))

    if app_response.status_code == 401:

        return 401

    else:

        return app_session

except:

    logger.debug('Exception')
```

From `sys.exc_info()` I see:

```
", verify = True"): unorderable types: Retry() < int()
```

If the error were something like `SessionAdapter() < int()` it might make more sense. But I don't know where the `Retry()` check is being made.

Does the import of `PoolManager` need to be done differently for Python 3? I'm using version 1.7.1 of python-urllib3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Your `try..except` masks any exceptions that happen. Remove it, and you should get a stack trace that allows you (or us, if you include it in the question) to pin-point where what comparison is being made.

Comment: I had simplified the code to focus on where the error was occurring. The `except` is much more robust than what I've shown and reports the error indicated at the end of the post.

Comment: Then please include the full traceback in your question.